# find the flow/option for casting

Tags: java, casting

I using the following code that I found using CTRL+SHIFT+G This the right code that I need to write at the end.

```
String Name =   ((Entitys) (typeAnno.getTel())).getName();
```

lets assume that I didnt find this code and 
the starting point for me is typeAnno.getTel() and from that I need to write the code above, is there some way that eclipse can help with that ?

Need some best practice on how to handle it (not for this code i need general solution ) step by step, and find even more cast options to complicated casting like.

```
namespace = ((Sch) ((Entitys) typeAnno.getTel()).eCont()).getName();
```

The problem is that if I didn't find the code in other classes I don't have clue how to start ? If casting option is possible or not and the option.

**The code here is specific code but my question in general ,assume that you have 
to find the casting option how would you do that ?**

Thanks!

Comment: There is no general answer to this.  If you need to cast like this, then you are making an assumption that the object referenced by `typeAnno.getTel()` is actually of a particular subclass.  In order to know which subclass, you need to look at the documentation (or class definition...)

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you have to write so many castings in your code something is going wrong with your design.

Let's review your case. What does `typeAnno.getTel()` return? Let's say it returns instance of class named `Phone`. It seems that this class extends `Entities` that declares method `getName()`. In this case you doe not need casting at all. Just say:

`String name = typeAnno.getTel().getName();`

Prior java 1.5 we sometimes needed casting when extracting objects from collection. But generics introduced in java 1.5 allow almost avoid writing casting at all.

So, the general answer to general question is. If you have to cast something review your design. In most cases you can avoid it at all.

Comment: my question is that assume I have to use it ,I didn't implement it and I have to use it,how would you go for it ? use F4 to see the implemented classes ...i need tips for this kind of scenario